# lexicographicMode in asyncio bulkCmd

Tags: pysnmp

While using Asynchronous pysnmp bulkCmd with asyncio, if requested OID have many values (like 1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2 that show MAC address learned by Cisco switch) or if using several OIDs in one request, I have problem that total number of OIDs in response limited by MTU/MSS of network, which means that not all OIDs received.

This problem can control if using lexicographicMode in Synchronous  bulkCmd, but Asynchronous bulkCmd generator haven`t that options.

It is possible to use getNext but it is significantly reducing performance because of increasing total number of packet (one request/response per OID).
Is there way to control that all "sub oid" received in response using Asynchronous bulkCmd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use the [maxRepetitions](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/hlapi/asyncio/manager/cmdgen/bulkcmd.html#pysnmp.hlapi.asyncio.bulkCmd) parameter to limit the number of response OIDs per each requested OID? It's `50` in this [example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncio/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations.html).

I believe the `lexicographicMode` option is designed to stop walking the MIB once the initial prefix goes out of scope. So it has only indirect influence over message size what makes it unreliable for the purpose.

Comment: My problem was that I didn`t received all necessary data (OID) because of maximum packet size. Using asyncio bulk request, only one udp packet receive and no matter, what value of maxRepetitions set. But I already find solution here [example](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncio/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations.html) - I can put bulk request in while loop and manual control, how much request/response will be sent.

Comment: The `maxRepetitions` parameter limits the number of "next" OIDs returned in response per each request OID. So that indirectly controls the UDP packet size, but it never influences the number of UDP packets you get in response (it's always one packet). So the solution is, like you say, to iterate over GETBULK limiting `maxRepetitions` to a sane value not to oversize the MTU.